# display name of day in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i want to display in output as : today is wednesday

my code:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'today is' 'day' ) from dual ;
```

it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the raw text you want in the output in double quotes in the format specification:

```
select to_char(sysdate, '"today is" day') from dual ;
```

Output (as of 2020-03-04)

```
today is wednesday
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=475b300903ddacd052f1f720a67c8473)

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat()` or the concatenation operator `||` to prepend the `'today is '` string.

```
SELECT concat('today is ', to_char(sysdate, 'day'))
       FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT 'today is ' || to_char(sysdate, 'day')
       FROM dual;
```

Comment: can there be some changes done to original code to get it right in select to_char(sysdate,'today is' 'day' ) from dual ;